# What should I do about a Tillandsia cyanea with accidentally removed roots?

Tags: watering, flowers, roots, tillandsia

My [*Tillandsia cyanea*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tillandsia_cyanea) was watered too much, and when I touched it, the top part with the leaves separated from the roots. I've found that some types of Tillandsia don't need roots, but is this it? Should I put it in the soil again?

Answer (score 3):

It may not need soil as it is an [epiphyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphyte) but it does need daily misting with distilled water or water that has had municipal chlorine/chloramine removed.

Try physically attaching it with rubber bands or wire to a porous medium:

- a bit of cork as sold in pet stores
- some nurseries sell material for orchids, a dense root like block which drains well
- a slab of bark

Then provide bright diffuse light and mist daily.  This will duplicate as close as possible the native environment in the rain forests.